# SOLR index status

Tags: solr, indexing, status

Can someone help me with URL to SOLR to get the status of a specific index.

I know with ElasticSearch it is easy:

```
http://domain-name:9200/_cluster/stats?<index-name>
```

What is the equivalent in SOLR ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

There are a few URLs that provide information about the current state of the Solr server:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/cores?wt=json
http://localhost:8080/solr/<corename>/admin/luke?wt=json&show=index&numTerms=0
http://localhost:8080/solr/<corename>/admin/system?wt=json
http://localhost:8080/solr/<corename>/replication?command=details&wt=json
```

A good way to discover these URLs are to watch the "Network" tab in your browsers debug tools while browsing the admin page for a Solr server. All the information provided in the UI is fetched from the above (and several other) URLs (you can also see these requests in the logs of your application container).